# How to toggle CSS class between buttons rendered with .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the color of a button from gray to blue when it gets clicked, and also change the color of the previously selected button back to gray, so only the current selected button is blue. However, the buttons are generated using the map() method, so with useState I get all buttons to change color at the same time:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bhaskara-ibb1e?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, {useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const menuItems = ["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"]
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
 
 return (
   <nav>
     {menuItems.map((days, idx) => {
       return (
         <button
           key={days}
           onClick={() => {
             setActive(!active)
           }}
           style={{backgroundColor: active? "blue" : ""}}
         >
           {days}
         </button>
       );
     })}
   </nav>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to store the currently selected button's name (or some Id) in the state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const menuItems = ["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"];
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState('');

  return (
    <nav>
      {menuItems.map((days, idx) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={days}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveButton(days);
            }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: activeButton === days ? "blue" : "" }}
          >
            {days}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Make sure your buttons have different names (as they are already now) for this to work and also because you're passing them in the `key` prop. If you think more than one button could have the same names in the future, add an `id` field too.

```
const menuItems = [{id: 1, name: "day 1"}, {id: 2, name: "day 2"}, {id: 3, name: "day 3"}];
```

Update the code accordingly. It won't be a good idea to pass array index in the `key` prop, if the situation changes. So, the `id` field will come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your `active` state from a bool to a number and set it to the index of the selected button

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(null);
```

And change your click event

```
 onClick={() => {
     setActive(idx)
 }}
```

And change your class condition to this

```
style={{backgroundColor: active === idx ? "blue" : ""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way:

```
export default function App() {
  const menuItems = ["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"];
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0); 

  return (
    <nav>
      {menuItems.map((days, idx) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={days}
            onClick={() => {
              setActive(idx);
            }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: idx===active ? "blue" : "" }}
          >
            {days}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

In this case, you selected index key

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the state `active` will get toggled no matter which button you're firing, so you'll be changing the state that every button depends on.

One of the ways for you to solve this problem would be for you to create a button component that has the state action, by doing this each state will belong to the instance of the component.

Once you created your component, map the component instead and pass in the props you need

```
export default function App() {
  const menuItems = ["day 1", "day 2", "day 3"];

  return menuItems.map((day, idx) => <Button key={idx} day={day} />);
}

function Button({ day }) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <button
      style={{ backgroundColor: active ? "blue" : "" }}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    >
      {day}
    </button>
  );
}
```